# why does eclipse complain "recursive method loop needs result type"?

Tags: scala, recursion, methods

I am editing following code in eclipse but it complains that "recursive method loop needs result type", so what's the error? Thanks.

```
package week2

object exercise {
  def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    def loop(acc: Int, n: Int) =
      if (n == 0) acc
      else loop(acc * n, n - 1)

    loop(1, n)
  }

  factorial(4)
}
```

Thanks for the answer. Yes, I missed something here. The correct is:

```
package week2

object exercise {
  def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    def loop(acc: Int, n: Int): Int =
      if (n == 0) acc
      else loop(acc * n, n - 1)

    loop(1, n)
  }                                               //> factorial: (n: Int)Int

  factorial(4)                                    //> res0: Int = 24
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules of the Scala language that any recursive method needs to be declared with a return type. `loop` is a recursive method and you didn't declare a return type for it (you only declared one for `factorial`, which doesn't necessarily need one). Therefore `scalac` (and by extension Eclipse) is telling you that the recursive method `loop` needs a return type.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Actually I am following the coursera course and I can see my code is exactly the same as the instructor's. But the video shows no error. So I guess it is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

As sepp2k indicated, it's restricted by compiler. Just wanted to add more info for clarification.

According to Scala's [local type inference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html) mechanism

> return types of methods can often be omitted since they correspond to the type of the body, which gets inferred by the compiler

Consider non-recursive function

```
def f(n: Int) = n % 2 == 0
```

where compiler can infer a result type, since it knows that expression `x % 2 == 0` will always produce type `Boolean`.

But when you deal with a recursive function, like

```
def f(n: Int) = if (n == 0) 1 else n * f(n-1)
```

Scala compiler won't infer the result type of `if (x == 0) 1 else x * f(x-1)` since that leads to an infinite loop. It can't even know that `f(x-1)` is an eligible operand for `*` operation, thus will give you an error `Cannot resolve reference * with such signature`.

Comment: Your reasoning is not true. It isn't hard to implement type inference for recursive functions in the general case but it is simply not done for Scala because it wouldn't fit into Scalas local type inference model.